# How to replace a method with a different method using mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

```
# actual code 
class x: 
   def func(self): 
      print("actual func")
   def other_func(self):
      print("do not touch me!")

# test method
class mockX():
   def func(self):
      print("mocked func")
```

I would like to test code which is using `x`. I would like to mock `x.func`, while all other methods of `x` should stay the same. The mocking is to complicated to just use something like `mock.return_value = "some value"`, which is why I created `mockX.func`.

How can I replace `x.func` with `mockX.func` using `unittest.mock`

Comment: You can make that `mockX` herit from `x` and only overload `func` and use an instance of `mockX` in the tests, this can be done cleanly with fixtures

Comment: Could you  please write this as an answer together with the actual code? Sounds like a great solution

Comment: You can just patch the function without patching the whole class, e.g. `@mock.patch("mymodule.x.func", mockX.func)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this as a second answer just to clarify what I meant in the comment. Also, as the question was about `unittest` I won't use `pytest` here, though I agree that with `pytest` this could be moved to a fixture.

As long as you don't need to mock the class itself, you can just mock the function:

```py
from unittest import mock

class X:
    def func(self):
        print("actual func")

    def other_func(self):
        print("do not touch me!")

class MockedX:
    def func(self):
        print("mocked func")


# the patch string has to be adapted if the class lives in another module,
# this is just for illustration
@mock.patch(f"{__name__}.X.func", MockedX.func)
def test_x():
    x = X()
    x.func()  # prints "mocked func"
    x.other_func()  # prints "do not touch me"
```

Note that `self` still points to the original object in this case.

You don't even need a separate class for the mock object - it is sufficient to write a mock function:

```py
def mocked_func(self):
    print("mocked func")

@mock.patch(f"{__name__}.X.func", mocked_func)
def test_x():
    x = X()
    x.func()  # prints "mocked func"
    x.other_func()  # prints "do not touch me"
```

`self` will also point to the original object here.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a small example.µ
It doesn't totally answer the question because it uses **pytest** and not only **unittest**. But it can give some ideas.

[The comment of mrbean-bremen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72350843/how-to-replace-a-method-with-a-different-method-using-mock?noredirect=1#comment127822051_72350843) can also help

```py
import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockerFixture


class x:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        print("Init X")

    def func(self):
        print("actual func")

    def other_func(self):
        print("do not touch me!")


def overload_func():
    print("mocked func")


@pytest.fixture()
def mockX(mocker: MockerFixture) -> x:
    x_fixture = x()

    mocker.patch.object(x_fixture, "func", wraps=overload_func)

    return x_fixture


def test_run(mockX: x):
    mockX.func()
    mockX.other_func()
    assert True == True
```